# How can one express relations in an array from the perspective of an array's member in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, testing, fibonacci

In ruby how do you declare a position in an array in relation to one of its members? I am trying to write tests for the Fibonnaci sequence whose terms are limited to four million and I have the following as my specs:

```
it 'creates an array of numbers with each member evaluating as the sum of the two previous members' do
  expect(fibonacci.each {|member| member == two_positions_back_from_member + one_position_back_from_member}).to eq(true)
end
```

I know that you can pin point the position of an array with, array[4]. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in relation to its members?

Answer (score 2):

You could of course find the member within the array, that gives you the index within the array, from which you can substract to get a relative position. In your example:

```
i = fibonacci.index(member); fibonacci[i-2] + fibonacci[i-1]
```

That said, you won't be able to test the fibonacci sequence like this, since it's -- well a sequence. And since it's infinite it would take forever. Unless your `fibonacci` is just an excerpt, of course.

Also, `each` will return `fibonacci`, so to `expect` this `.to be(true)` is probably not what you want. Try using `map` instead of `each` and then `expect` `.to eq(fibonacci)`.

Comment: Good point. allow me to provide some more context in the question. I forgot to mention that four million limits the terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumberable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
fibonacci.each_cons(3).all? {|fn2, fn1, fn| fn == fn1 + fn2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the first two elements of the Fibonacci sequence ("seed values") are 0 and 1 (as opposed to 1 and 1, which is sometimes seen); that is, `0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,...`.

I think the best way to do this efficiently is to create an array `fib` of the first first `N=4_000_000` Fibonacci numbers and a corresponding hash `bif` such that:

```
bif[fib[i]] = i
```

The following is one way to do this for the first `N` Fibonacci numbers:

```
N = 10
fib = [0,1,1]
fib_minus_two = fib_minus_one = 1
bif = {}

(3..N-2).each do |n|
  f = fib_minus_two + fib_minus_one
  fib << f
  bif[f] = n
  fib_minus_two = fib_minus_one
  fib_minus_one = f
end

bif.each { |f,i| puts "# bif[#{f}]=>#{i}, fib[#{i}]=>#{f}" } 
  # bif[2]=>3, fib[3]=>2
  # bif[3]=>4, fib[4]=>3
  # bif[5]=>5, fib[5]=>5
  # bif[8]=>6, fib[6]=>8
  # bif[13]=>7, fib[7]=>13
  # bif[21]=>8, fib[8]=>21
```

For the Fibonacci number `0`, you can test that

```
fib[0] = 0
```

For the Fibonacci number `1`, you can test that

```
fib[1] = 1
fib[2] = 1
```

and for any Fibonacci number `n`, `n > 1` you can test that

```
i = bif[n]
fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
```

Of course, `N = 4_000_000` is not a problem.